# Create Nested Python Dictionary From Tuple of Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an iterable of keys like `('a', 'b', 'c')` that I want to correspond to an entry in a dictionary I am building. I am looking for a one-linerish way to build this dictionary from multiple tuples.

Input:

```
keys = ('a', 'b', 'c')
value = 'bar'
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'bar'}}}
```

I have been trying things using defaultdict, but haven't really gotten the grasp of it. The one-liner requirement is pretty soft, but I was hoping to get a really small footprint for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reduce`<sup>1</sup> here:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, keys[::-1], value)
```

Or, use the iterator returned by `reversed`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(keys), value)
```

A lot of people might not like this too much.  Unless you're really into functional programming in python, this is a bit opaque.  A simpler solution takes only 3 lines:

```
>>> keys = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> value = 'bar'
>>> for c in reversed(keys):
...   value = {c: value}
... 
>>> value
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'bar'}}}
```

and doesn't rely on any *slightly obscure* builtin functions.

FWIW, I'm not sure which version I prefer ...

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>`functools.reduce` in python3.x which also exists in python2.6+ to ease py3k transitions IIRC</sup>